# Pagination: Haven't I seen this question before?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, pagination

I have some questions about how pagination works, particularly when viewing the "firehose" at https://stackoverflow.com/questions. Right now, the paginated links look something like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest
```

This means that when I click the "next" button, the next page is calculated *based on the current state of Stack Overflow*, rather than the state of the site when I first started paging through question. This means that "next" may in fact show me questions I have already seen, and if I'm a slow reader I may not actually make any forward progress.

This is a frustrating experience and makes it difficult to discover questions "outside of my comfort zone".

Would it make sense to modify the pagination mechanism such that it includes a reference to the base question from which the pages were initially calculated?  E.g., if I start browsing and the first question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946141/can-anyone-explain-line-number-3-of-this-code), pagination links might look something like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&base=47946141&sort=newest
```

In this model the server would calculate a list of questions older than the base, and use that to generate the pagination. I could always see newer questions simply by returning to https://stackoverflow.com/questions.

I realize that this is effectively proposing a "cursor" for paginated links. Is that crazy talk?

Comment: There's a recent question about this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360984/avoid-duplicate-questions-while-paginating) but it never got an official answer.

Comment: I see that not only was that question heavily downvoted, but it also managed to never mention "pagination", thus foiling my attempts to see if this had already been asked. I hoped that I've provided a slightly more palatable phrasing of the question.  Time will tell, I guess.

Comment: I don't think this would really be feasible. Not only are new questions being added to the list, the existing questions are being re-sorted as they are voted on, questions are being closed/deleted, etc. Keeping the same order would require the order and selection of questions be cached specifically for you such that it doesn't change until you want it to.

Comment: I figured "select all questions older than <x>" and then apply the same heuristics that are currently in use would be a relatively simple improvement, but I didn't actually realize that the list at `/questions` was sorted by anything other than chronological order. So maybe that wouldn't really help all that much.

Answer (score 9):

This is far from trivial to implement.

Say you take the *"select all questions older than `x`"* approach, what would the page number then be?

If each page contains 10 items, and there are 23 questions *younger* than `x`, you'd end up halfway through page 3:

```
page | questions
 1   |  1 - 10
 2   | 11 - 20
 3   | 21 - 30
```

Now what if you'd want to go to page 2? Where would you navigate to? To the range of items `14-23`? Revert back to default pagination, `11-20`? Then you'd be missing questions `21-23`.

We haven't even touched handling deleted questions, yet. A `base` parameter would only shift the problem to a different index. If a question older than `x` is deleted, all questions after the deleted one shift forward, affecting ***every*** page after the one containing your `base`.

On the technical end, as far as databases are concerned, a `TAKE X SKIP Y` is *fast*. Comparing timestamps / ids isn't.

---

Long story short:

Timestamp based pagination is a pain to implement, and even more of a pain to explain to a normal user.

The current system is fast, easy to explain and easy to understand.

Comment: also, probably for the same reasons explained here, that's consistent with how pagination works in many sites. Actually, I don't remember knowing any site (with dynamic user-content like here) that uses timestamped snapshot of pages.